# package org.apache.commons.io does not exist

Tags: java

I extracted our previously built jar file and try to compile Java code again using `JDeveloper`. It gave multiple error due to missing jars then I imported jars to my project then all error disappear except one

> package org.apache.commons.io does not exist

I searched a lot and tried ever solution from web but its still not working. Can someone help me in this regards, I imported with `import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;`

> Errors Error(26,39):  package org.apache.commons.io does not exist
>       Error(82,17):  cannot find variable IOUtils

Comment: Did you include the jar as part of the build path in the jdeveloper?

Comment: Thanks Kevin for response. yes I included the jar file similarly I did for all other error. For this error I included commons-codec 1.8 and commons-io-2.4 but issue is still there.

Answer (score 2):

it started working now. I downloaded commons-io-2.4 from a different resource and imported to my project. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, solved by adding 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4' to dependencies in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation (
        'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    )
}
```